# SDL_BlitScaled doesn't work

Tags: c++, sdl

here is my c++ code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
  SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
  gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "test", 0,0,640,480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
  gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
  SDL_Surface* x = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,50,50,32,0xFF,0xFF00,0xFF0000,0XFF000000);
  SDL_Surface* y = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,640,480,32,0xFF,0xFF00,0xFF0000,0XFF000000);
  SDL_Rect a = {0,0,50,50};
  SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
  SDL_FillRect(x,&a,SDL_MapRGBA(x->format,255,255,0,255));
  SDL_Rect dest = {0,0,100,100};

  SDL_BlitScaled( x, &a, y, &dest ); //Does nothing

  dest.x = 200;

  SDL_BlitSurface( x, &a, y, &dest );

  SDL_Texture* t;
  t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer,y);
  SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer,t,NULL,NULL);
  SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
  SDL_Delay(2000);
return 0;
}
```

well,when you compile this code,you will see there is ONLY ONE rect on the screen.The function `SDL_BlitScaled` does nothing.

I'm working with Archlinux,gcc 4.8.2,SDL 2.0.1

---

According to Retired Ninja's answer,I changed my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
  SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO );
  gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow( "test", 0,0,640,480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
  gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
  SDL_Surface* x = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,50,50,32,0xFF,0xFF00,0xFF0000,0XFF000000);
  SDL_Surface* y = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,640,480,32,0xFF,0xFF00,0xFF0000,0XFF000000);
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer,255,255,255,255);
  SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

  SDL_Rect a = {0,0,25,25};
  SDL_FillRect(x,&a,SDL_MapRGBA(x->format,255,255,0,255));
  a.x = 25;a.y = 25;
  SDL_FillRect(x,&a,SDL_MapRGBA(x->format,255,0,0,255));

  SDL_FillRect(y,&y->clip_rect,SDL_MapRGBA(y->format,255,0,255,128));

  SDL_Rect dest = {0,0,100,100};
  SDL_Rect x_rect = {0,0,50,50};
  SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(x,SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
  SDL_BlitScaled( x, &x_rect, y, &dest );

  SDL_Texture* t;
  t = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer,y);
  SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer,t,NULL,NULL);
  SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
  SDL_Delay(2000);
return 0;
}
```

there is another problem appeared.I try to copy `x` into `y`,The `x` covered `y` entirely,even through there are transparent area in `x`.But if I don't use SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE,the alpha of the area copied into `y` will be set into 128,which is not my purpose.

Comment: All I want is to copy a SDL_Surface `x` into `y` by using SDL_BlitScaled,but it doesn't work for me.I hope that I can make myself understood clearly,but English is not my naive language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling `y` with a color makes it work.

I added:

```
SDL_FillRect(y, &y->clip_rect, SDL_MapRGBA(x->format, 255, 0, 0, 255));
```

after the `SDL_FillRect` for `x` and it worked.

Some further experimentation of just filling a portion of `y` with alpha leads me to believe that `SDL_BlitScaled` isn't copying the alpha from the source surface so unless the dest surface has alpha where the destination rect is you won't see the result.

Some more experimentation shows that the default blend mode for a surface is `SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND` and changing the mode for `y` to `SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE` also makes it work.

Comment: Cool!Thanks for your answer!But I still have a question.I updated it on the post.I will be very grateful if you have a look.

Comment: At this point I am unsure what your goal is.  If you want parts of `x` to be transparent then set their alpha to 0.

Comment: X:half transparent,half not,Y:alpha 128.Then copy X into Y,the transparent part of X will become translucent,and the other part will become non-transparent,am I clear?  PS:I tried another way to scale the picture,so this question is not so important any more.